# How to hide toolbar with drawer layout and still be be able to use the open drawer button(three lines)?

Tags: hide, android-toolbar

I'm new to android and I'm trying to hide toolbar in drawer

layout for a time now but couldn't do it.If I change primary

color to 0 opacity then I get "A TaskDescription's primary

color should be opaque" error I know the reason of the error

so I've to set 255 opacity to primary color as taskDescription

takes primary color. I want the following UI;

[UI[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyO4.jpg)

I've used following theme;

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     Customize your theme here.
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

manifest ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I did manage to transparent the status bar by setting up primaryDark color to opacity 0.

color.xml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00303f9f</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="toolbarcolor">#00ffffff</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tooolbar.hide() method or instead you can use scrollbars to whole activity with toolbars so that it will give a hide toolbar behaviour
 or just give a trasparent color to toolbar
I hope it will help a little bit